# Filtering a string variable

Tags: stata

I am using the following code snipped, which was provided as a solution to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57347018/matching-variable-strings):

```
clear
input str15 v1 str75 v2
"045672, 19274" "[045672, 19274; 056843, 20483] AAA8793307546; [061483, 21124] AZS69482148"
"061483, 21124" "[045672, 19274; 056843, 20483] AAA8793307546; [061483, 21124] AZS69482148"
"068346, 32948" "[068346, 32948] BGJ569788313" 
end

split v2, parse("[")
drop v2

reshape long v2, i(v1) j(id)
keep if strpos(v2, v1)
drop id

list

     +---------------------------------------------------------------+
     |            v1                                              v2 |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | 045672, 19274   045672, 19274; 056843, 20483] AAA8793307546;  |
  2. | 061483, 21124                      061483, 21124] AZS69482148 |
  3. | 068346, 32948                     068346, 32948] BGJ569788313 |
     +---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How can I only keep `AAA8793307546`, `AZS69482148` etc. in the second variable?

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions also work here:

```
replace v2 = regexs(0) if(regexm(v2, "[A-Z]+[0-9]+"))

list

     +-------------------------------+
     |            v1              v2 |
     |-------------------------------|
  1. | 045672, 19274   AAA8793307546 |
  2. | 061483, 21124     AZS69482148 |
  3. | 068346, 32948    BGJ569788313 |
     +-------------------------------+
```

Comment: Regular expressions are indeed a potential solution but depending on the use case they can get complex fast.